# How to get the ssl URLs right when laravel is behind an app gateway

Tags: laravel, ssl

I have laravel behind an app gateway, where the gateway is removing the SSL and sending the request on via port 80.

I have a Laravel 9 app behind an Azure App Gateway/WAF. This device strips off the SSL and presents port 80 traffic to the web servers. There are several problems.

My traffic arrives on the first (login) page, but the login form is rendered with http:// which comes from the url() helper function. I fixed that with advice from a Stack Overflow article which suggested adding:

```
    resolve(\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::class)->forceScheme('https');
```

in the Boot method of the Route Service Provider. I did that, and the URLs are now coming out as https://. All good, I thought.

Now, my post to https://..../signin is 404.

I thought of replacing all my calls to url() with secure_url(). Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you make the post call to the gateway or to app service directly?

Comment: The post call will go to the app gateway, get stripped down to a non-SSL post call to port 80.